# not all fields of javascript dynamic form are being posted

Tags: javascript, forms

I am submitting a dynamically created FORM (created via JS), however, not all of the INPUT elements added to the form are being passed to the destination.

My original failed attempt to do this was to add new elements to an existing form, however multiple questions here on StackOverflow pointed to a solution of creating a new form with the information I want to submit, and submit that.

If I create the form, and add new INPUT elements (VALUE and VALUE2 in the script below) via JavaScript, this works.   The problem comes when I try and clone the elements from the original form to the new form.  Those fields (FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 and BUTTON1) and their values do not exist in the posted dataset, even though the addition of the new form to the document occurs as the last thing before the new form is submitted.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form id="public" method="POST">
            <input id="field1" hidden type="text"   value="field1"><BR>
            <input id="field2" hidden type="text"   value="field2"><BR>
            <input id="field3"        type="text"   value=""><BR>
            <input id="button1"       type="submit" value="i'm a button"><BR>
    </form>
    <div id="location"></div>

    <script>
        form=document.querySelector("#public");

        form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            newform=document.createElement("form");
            newform.setAttribute("hidden","");
            newform.id="hiddenForm";
            newform.method="post";
            newform.action="/submit_destination.php";

            field_value=document.createElement("input");
            field_value.setAttribute("hidden","");
            field_value.name="value";
            field_value.setAttribute("value","10");
            newform.appendChild(field_value);

            field_value2=document.createElement("input");
            field_value2.setAttribute("hidden","");
            field_value2.name="value2";
            field_value2.setAttribute("value","the text value goes here");
            newform.appendChild(field_value2);

            InputElements = form.getElementsByTagName("Input");

            i=0;
            while(i < InputElements.length)
            {
                newEL = form.querySelector("#"+InputElements[i]['id']).cloneNode( true );
                newform.appendChild(newEL);
                i++;
            }

            document.querySelector("#location").appendChild(newform);

            newform.submit();

        });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The resulting POSTed variables to a simple `var_dump($_POST);` are

```
array(2) { 
   ["value"]=> string(2) "10" 
   ["value2"]=> string(24) "the text value goes here" 
}
```

None of the elements added to the form during the while loop are being added to the POSTed dataset (which is important for my final use case as other asynchronous activities will be adding to the "public" form, thus I need to capture them)

If I page-back my browser from the submit_destination.php page, I can see the modified HTML, and it includes all the fields in the dynamically created "hiddenform" form, including those duplicated from the "public" form.  However the public form elements were not included in the posted data set.

I'm at a loss to understand how only part of the FORM is being posted to the destination.